# How to align elements on the background?

Tags: html, css, background, alignment

I am trying to make a homepage on my website with 4 round buttons in a row and I want them to be on a horizontal line that is drawn on the background image.
Of Course I want them to stay aligned to the line even when the browser windows is resized but I have no idea how to do this or if this is even possible.

I tried working with percentages both on the background and on the buttons, but the buttons resize into the upper left corner so they wont stay even with the background.

**EDIT - 
got it almost working, the only problem I have is that it is not aligning perfect on the percentages, when the window is really small the buttons go a little bit under the line and when the window is bigger the button goes a little bit above the line.**

My HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body id="menu-body">
    <div id="menu-div">
        <h1></h1>
        <div id="menu">
            <a href="" class="menu-link"><img src="" alt="" class="menu-img"/></a>
            <a href="" class="menu-link"><img src="" alt="" class="menu-img"/></a>
            <a href="" class="menu-link"><img src="" alt="" class="menu-img"/></a>
            <a href="" class="menu-link"><img src="" alt="" class="menu-img"/></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS

```
#menu-body {
    background-image: url('../img/background.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-color: #1B1B1B;
}

#menu-div {
    width: 100%;
}

#menu {
    width: 100%;
}

.menu-img {
    float: left;
    width: 24%;
    margin-top: 15%;
}
```

Comment: can you please create a plunker with your html / or just include you html in the question - do you want the buttons to be vertically align as well?

Comment: I only want them to align horizontally

Comment: acording to the code you posted and granted you give these <a> tag a value they are aligned on the top left corner of the screen. isn't that what you are looking for?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/omsbf28L/2/ here is the fiddle, it is really ugly because I cannot get the original transparent png's on the site, but if you resize your window you can see the images moving from the red line(background) on the right.

Comment: you can fix the screen size issue with media queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: I thought about that, but isn't there another cleaner way? Maybe with JQuery?

Comment: media queries are cleaner than jquery

Comment: Allright, then I want to thank you for helping me, I'll play around with media queries! Cheers!

Comment: good luck dude, keep up the good work :) !

Answer (score 0):

give them the property float:left;

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's your target here but an easy solution is using the gud'ol flexbox property. You can set the container of the rounded buttons with 'display:flex', 'justify-content:center' and 'flex-wrap:nowrap' and that show keep them aligned but remove the percentages, just leave the anchors there and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I tried this, but it is not working, it puts the buttons vertically at first, I played around with the flex and content but it did not work.